# Differences between GrapheneDB and Graph Story

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j, graph-databases, graphenedb

What are the differences between [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com/) and [Graph Story](https://www.graphstory.com/)?

Having skimmed their sites, it looks like Graph Story is trying to be a one stop shop for all things operations, whereas GrapheneDB is trying to focus more on offering specific services.

On GrapheneDB's website, they list their features as:

- 24x7 Monitoring
- Cloud Scaling
- Support
- Backups
- Operational
- Dashboard
- Extensible

Graph Story highlights:

- Support of Many Languages (PHP, Java, Python, C#, Swift and Ruby)
- Offers Staging and Production Instances, Backups and Monitoring for one price

It seems like one major difference is that GrapheneDB works well with Azure/AWS, whereas Graph Story hosts the content themselves.

The standard $50 / month options for each are:

[GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com/aws.html):

- Spatial and custom plugins/extensions
- SSL secured database connection
- 24x7 Monitoring
- Manual & scheduled daily backups
- Configurable memory map and execution guard settings
- Standard support
- Target downtime: <2 hours/month

[Graph Story](http://www.graphstory.com/pricing.php):

- 2 GB Memory
- 40 GB Storage
- 2 Cores
- 3 TB Transfer
- Daily Automated Backups